# Taking a slice of a byte array in Visual c++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++

I want to take a slice of an array that drops the first byte, i.e. something like myArray[1..myArray->Length].  How do I do this in Visual C++/CLI?

Thanks,
FM

Answer (score 1):

If this is a managed array (`cli::array`), then you could use [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx), which is the managed framework structure for array "slicing" and partitioning.

Comment: I couldn't make ArraySegment<T> work so I used Array::Copy(pkt, 1, pktmsg, 0, len - 1); instead.  During my reading I discovered that .NET forces you to copy arrays in all circumstances so this should work fine.  Thanks for the tip tho.

Comment: @FrankMiller ArraySegment is intended not to "copy" the values (it doesn't copy), but give you a way to provide access to an array slice without a copy.  You can't use the results as an array itself, though.